# Divide time column in time spans based on several columns

Tags: vba, if-statement, excel-formula

So far I have managed fine using Excel's formulas, so I might not need VBA to solve this problem.

I want to create time spans in column V based on the times in column O. The time spans are: 00-05, 05-07, 07-09, 09-15, 15-18 and 18-00. Thus far I have been using the formula (example for row 25):

```
=IF([@Old]="","",IF([@Old]*24<5,"00-05",IF([@Old]*24<7,"05-07",IF([@Old]*24<9,"07-09",IF([@Old]*24<15,"09-15",IF([@Old]*24<18,"15-18","18-00"))))))
```

But I want the time spans to be conditional on column M as well, so that fx the time spans for rows 41 to 42 should still be 05-07, because they are in the batch that started in 05-07 (row 31). I have uploaded what the result should look like in the picture below. I also have a column that counts the start and end of the batch (from 1 and upwards). This might help to solve the issue, but I'm not sure how to do the expand the conditional if-statement.

[image: Current]
[image: How it should look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (this works from cell F2, since other rows are being checked - M1 and R1 in this case, which have no simple reference in a teble-ish way):

```
=IF([@batch]<>M1,IF([@Old]="","",IF([@Old]*24<5,"00-05",IF([@Old]*24<7,"05-07",IF([@Old]*24<9,"07-09",IF([@Old]*24<15,"09-15",IF([@Old]*24<18,"15-18","18-00")))))),V1)
```

Basically I added an extra if to check if it is a new batch.

```
IF([@batch]<>M1,(do the long calculation), (use the same value as above))
```

Comment: I will try it in a minute. Why are you using the R-column?

Comment: Because I didn't pay proper attention... Sorry, use column V, where the formula itself resides.

Comment: Np :) Hmm, just tried. Doesn't seem to be working. The error message is: "You have inserted to many arguments in this function".

Comment: My bad. Working perfectly now. Thx!

Comment: Oh, I'm glad. :) Please mark as answer if this helped you solve the problem.

Comment: I have another question which relates to the same dataset, but involves ordering and possibly vlookup based on the N-column. Should I post it here or add it as a new question?

Comment: You should add a new question.

Comment: Added. Please have a look :)